# Why does this java program outputs false?

Tags: java, equals

The following java code, which outputs false:

```
class Value {
int i;
}
public class EqualsMethod2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Value v1 = new Value();
Value v2 = new Value();
v1.i = v2.i = 100;
System.out.println(v1.equals(v2));
}
}
```

Why isn't the result true instead? While reading some Java documentation I've found the following answer: *the default behavior of equals() is to compare handles*. But aren't v1 and v2 handles?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why periodically ? Wouldn't you rather get notified of a change anytime one occurs ?

Comment: What's the problem? Getting data from the DOM? Doing things periodically?

Comment: Fieldset + Legend is designed for grouping a set of fields together, for a single field you should use `<label>` instead.

Comment: @Quentin I love the fieldset + legend effect

Comment: @Halim Qarroum I just want to test it

Comment: @bloomingsmilez: You should use CSS for getting the "effect". Start with `<div class="fieldsetlabel"><label>Enter Color Name:</label><input type="text"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `setInterval` to check periodically what you need

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var myInterval,
           myColorName,
           myDelay = xxx;
           function onLoad(){
               startTimer();  
           }
           function startTimer(){
               myInterval  = setInterval(function(){
                   myColorName = document.forms['form1'].elements['textbox'].value;
                   if(myColorName.length>0){
                       //do what you want with your color        
                   }
               },myDelay);
           }
           function stopTimer(){
               clearInterval(myInterval);
           }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <form name="form1">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter Color Name:</legend>
            <input type="text" name="textbox"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to get value periodically, because you wont be able to get data immediately when the data is typed in the input.

Try `<input type=¨text¨ name=¨some¨ onkeyup=¨typed(this.value)¨/>`

```
function typed(value)
{
console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: What are these funny quotes?

Comment: @Bergi i dont know what happened to my ubuntu, now the single quotes, double quotes key need to to pressed two times to type but the output is like this